# GCP Http loadbalancer tcp connection behavior under load

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

Let say i have 1 GCP `http load balancer` and 2 `webserver` in backend.

Now if 100 user(browser) hit my service, I know that load balancer has 100 tcp connection open.
But will loadbalancer also open 100 tcp connection to my webserver ?

**In short: Does GCP http load balancer do `tcp connection pooling` to my webservers or not?**

Comment: AFAIK connection pooling is not used with backends: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https HTTP connections are open/closed per HTTP request.

Comment: John, post your comment as an answer as it is on point.

Comment: the link shared says "The load balancer terminates incoming connections, and then opens new connections from the load balancer to the backends"... but doesnt say "per HTTP request"...